# Simplifying a Kullback-Leibler divergence

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization, normal-distribution, approximation, statistical-inference

I want to find an approximation of a mixture of probability distributions that minimises the Kullback-Leibler divergence (KLD).
I need to verify my result, as it seems suspect.

We have a joint distribution
\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) = \prod_{k=1}^{K} \big( \pi_{k} \, p_{k} (\mathbf{x}) \big)^{z_{k}},
\end{align}
where $p_{k}(\mathbf{x})$ is a probability density function, and $\pi_{k}$ is a weight that must satisfy $0 < \pi_{k} \leq 1$ together with $\sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_{k} = 1$.
Here $\mathbf{z} = \begin{bmatrix}
z_{1} & z_{2} & \cdots & z_{K}
\end{bmatrix}^{T}$ is a $1$-of-$K$ binary variable, where $z_{k} \in \{ 0, 1 \}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{K} z_{k} = 1$.
That is to say, one element of $\mathbf{z}$ must equal one, while the rest must equal zero.
The marginal of $\mathbf{x}$ is the $K$-component mixture
\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{\mathbf{z}} p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \pi_{k} \, p_{k}(\mathbf{x}).
\end{align}
We now introduce a similarly defined joint distribution
\begin{align}
q(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) =  \prod_{k=1}^{K} \big( \pi_{k} \, q(\mathbf{x}) \big)^{z_{k}},
\end{align}
where $q(\mathbf{x})$ is a probability density function.
I want to find the optimal $q(\mathbf{x})$ that minimises the KLD
\begin{align}
D_{\text{KL}} (q (\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) \, || \, p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) ) &= \sum_{\mathbf{z}} \int q(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) \log \Big( \frac{ q(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) }{ p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z})  } \Big) d \mathbf{x}.
\end{align}
I believe the KLD can be simplified as follows:
\begin{align}
D_{\text{KL}} (q (\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) \, || \, p(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) ) &= \sum_{\mathbf{z}} \int \Bigg( \prod_{i=1}^{K} \big( \pi_{i} \, q(\mathbf{x}) \big)^{z_{i}}  \Bigg) \Bigg(  \sum_{i=1}^{K} z_{i} \log \Big( \frac{ q(\mathbf{x}) }{ p_{i} (\mathbf{x}) }  \Big) \Bigg) d \mathbf{x} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{K} \int \pi_{k} \, q(\mathbf{x}) \log \Big( \frac{ q(\mathbf{x}) }{ p_{k} (\mathbf{x}) }  \Big) d \mathbf{x} \\
&= \int q (\mathbf{x}) \, \log \Big(  \frac{q(\mathbf{x})}{ f (\mathbf{x})  } \Big) d \mathbf{x} - \log(Z),
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{Z}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{K} \big( p_{k} (\mathbf{x}) \big)^{\pi_{k}} 
\end{align}
and $Z$ is a normalising constant.
The KLD is minimised when $q(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{x})$.
Is my simplification of the KLD correct?

Comment: For what it is worth, it looks good to me.